# Avoid delay playing audio over music from other apps (Soundcloud)

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

So as I'm writing this, I'm realizing just how specific this issue is...

I'm making an iOS app which plays sounds over other apps' music, but with *some* apps (so far only *one*, actually), I'm experiencing a lag when playing sounds that doesn't occur when this app isn't playing its music, i.e.

1. Start playback using the *Soundcloud* app
2. Load my app
3. Press button to play sound
4. Sound plays

If I omit step 1 (or use a different app, see below), there is no (perceivable) delay between 3 & 4, but keeping step 1 there, I hear a small (~200ms) delay in the playback start.

I have tried using `AVAudioPlayer` using `[player prepareToPlay]`:

```
- (void)prepPlayer:(Sound *)sound
{
  NSURL* pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[sound getStoragePath] isDirectory:NO];
  AVAudioPlayer* newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pathURL error:&error];
  [newPlayer prepareToPlay];
}

- (void)playSound
{
  player.currentTime = 0;
  [player play];
}
```

and `AVAudioPlayerNode` / `AVAudioEngine` / `AVAudioMixerNode` using:

```
- (void)prepQuickSound:(Sound *)sound
{
  self.audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
  self.audioMixerNode = [[AVAudioMixerNode alloc] init];

  [self.audioEngine attachNode:self.audioMixerNode];
  [self.audioEngine connect:self.audioMixerNode to:self.audioEngine.outputNode format:nil];

  self.player = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
  [audioEngine attachNode:playerNode];
  [audioEngine connect:playerNode to:mixerNode format:nil];

  NSURL* pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[sound getStoragePath] isDirectory:NO];
  NSError *audioLoadError = nil;  
  self.quickAudioFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:pathURL error:&audioLoadError];
}

- (void)playQuickSound
{
  [self.player stop];
  [self.player scheduleFile:self.quickAudioFile atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];
  [self.player play];
}
```

...but I see the same delay regardless.

This delay doesn't happen when playing music using the Music (iTunes) app, or Spotify, so I guess it's something that the SoundCloud app is doing in particular, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can get around it.

I'm really hoping someone here has had a similar issue and solved it - I can't find anything from my google searches...

Comment: Have you considered claiming the audio session before starting to play audio in your app?

Comment: I have, but the only category that fits my need is `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` (I want to play over other apps), and after trying all legal/valid settings of `mode`, `routeSharingPolicy` and `options` I still get the delay